# How can I set PATH with space in cmake?

Tags: bash, cmake

I am using a CMake custom target to prepend a PATH and execute a command. The current CMakeLists.txt is like this (partial):

```
add_custom_target(${target}
    COMMAND PATH=${SOME_PATH}/bin:$ENV{PATH} ${SOME_PROGRAM})
```

The problem is that when the `$ENV{PATH}` contains a space, the produced Makefile is like:

```
"PATH=/some path/bin:/bin" some_program
```

But actually it should be like this otherwise bash will not work:

```
PATH="/some path/bin:/bin" some program
```

How should I write the CMakeLists.txt to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `COMMAND` option does not understand shell's `var=value command ...`. You can write like this:

```
add_custom_target(${target}
    COMMAND env PATH=${SOME_PATH}/bin:$ENV{PATH} ${SOME_PROGRAM})
#           ^^^
```

Or

```
add_custom_target(${target}
    COMMAND export PATH=${SOME_PATH}/bin:$ENV{PATH} \; ${SOME_PROGRAM})
#           ^^^^^^                                  ^^
```

Comment: I did not know the `env` command before

Comment: just updated and added another way by using `export`.